# Test Webcam via Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam

I am looking for a "test your webcam" flash movie like [this one](http://www.sillywebcam.com/others/?demo=test-your-webcam) that is free and OK to use in a closed environment.

I need the camera testing only, no server side processing of the video stream. It is thought as a small online tool for a client.

Is this possible? Does anybody know a freely usable solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/media/Camera.html#includeExamplesSummary

shows a simple example for how to use the camera class. i've also uploaded an example here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/598146/cam.swf

for more tips on using the camera class take a look here http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2008/06/16/camera-class-quirks-with-fms/

Josh