# Looking for a browser based webcam streaming and capture lib/framework

Tags: javascript, flash, html, actionscript, video-streaming

What I want to do is have control over the streams so I can send them wherever I want, have it interface w/a mic and cam, and the ability to capture and record them. At this point I don't have any specific specs or limitations. It will be used in a commercial project so the license must allow for that. Free and OSS is preferably, but commercial and proprietary is not out of the question if it's worth it.

I don't see html5 as a viable solution at this point so I'm assuming it's going to rely on flash which is fine, but I do not know actionscript. I'm not opposed to learning it, and assume I could pick it up fine within a week, but keep that in mind. If I have to build something myself from the actionscript libraries (I assume they provide enough functionality) I can do so, but I'm hoping for a quicker solution than that.

Comment: html5 is not yet viable because it's in alpha state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the flash applet, you would have to integrate it with a server running Flash Media Server, SmartFox Server, etc

Comment: Just did a quick glance over flash media server and that seems like a good option, but why would I _have_ to integrate it with such a server? I'm not saying I want to do it necessarily, but could I not provide my own solution for recording and streaming it?

Answer (score 1):

Flash has had webcam support built in for awhile. Checkout their help pages at: [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d49.html)

Check out this question for more links too:

[Test Webcam via Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986303/test-webcam-via-flash)